# Can you add a tab to the ribbon of a document in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

So I'm building a file with a bunch of Macros on it to clean data that other people in my organization can use(standardize Email addresses, phone numbers etc etc)

I thought I'd add a Tab to the ribbon and then place a bunch of buttons on there to activate these Macros, but I'm not sure if there's a way to make it so that if anyone opens the file it becomes available or if I can only edit my own Ribbon.

Is there a way to tie a new tab to the Document itself?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible on a file. You can add buttons to the ribbon by creating an Excel Add-In, but I think you need to install that to Excel generally, it won't be file specific. In your case it might make more sense to have the first sheet in your file be dedicated to the buttons that you wanted in the ribbon?

Comment: That is probably the solution I'll end up going with, but I thought I'd ask here in case there was something I didn't know or couldn't figure out.

Comment: Yes it's possible.   [See here](https://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html)

Comment: Yes you can tie a new tab to the Workbook itself. But the tab will only be visible if the Workbook is activated.

Comment: 1. You can add controls on ribbon only for the interval the respective workbook is open. "Document in Excel" does not have much of a meaning. 2. A table in ribbon is an abstract concept. You can create a new tab and add controls in groups.